# Prevent myself from accidentally deleting a file

Tags: files, permissions, rm

I'm a user (not root) on a RHEL server. I want to be able to continue editing a file in my home directory, but set a permission so I don't accidentally delete it. Is this possible? Can I make it so I need to be secondarily prompted before deleting it (eg. "Are you sure? y/n")?

Comment: what'd be the difference between "editing it" down to zero bytes and deleting it?

Comment: I'm more confident that I won't edit it down to zero bytes.

Comment: In a startup file, such as `.bashrc`, you could add an alias `alias rm='rm -i'` so that you'll always get the 'are you sure' prompt.  It can be dangerous to start depending on this behaviour; better to make typing `rm -i` a muscle habit.

Comment: You may be looking for the wrong solution, you may be better with revision control (subversion (svn), mercurial (hg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You remove a file by *unlinking* it to the directory it's referenced in (a file could also be referenced in more than one directory, or several times (with different names) to one directory, that's what we usually call hard links).

The permissions that matter then are not that of the file, but that of the directory it's linked to.

So if you place it in a directory you don't have write access to:

```
mkdir important-files
echo test > important-files/myfile
chmod a-w important-files # make the directory not writable
```

Then you won't be able to delete `myfile`, but you'll still be able to modify the file as long as it's writable.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to continue editing a file in my home directory, but set a permission so I don't accidentally delete it. Is this possible?

In short, not per file with the usual Unix permissions. Perhaps [ACLs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-acls.html) can provide such fine-grained control?

> Can I make it so I need to be secondarily prompted before deleting it (eg. "Are you sure? y/n")?

A common workaround for this is setting an alias for `rm` to `rm -i`, e. g. in `~/.bash_aliases` (if supported by your distribution), `~/.bashrc` or even globally in `/etc/bashrc` (which may be overwritten by updates of the  `bash` package, so better don't use this option):

```
$ cat .bash_aliases 
alias rm='rm -i'
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a subdirectory, and remove write access from yourself, you won't be able to remove any files in the directory, but you can still modify them.

```
$ mkdir dir ; echo something > dir/foo ; chmod a-w dir
$ $EDITOR dir/foo
$ rm -rf dir/
rm: cannot remove 'dir/foo': Permission denied
```

Though you could still destroy or truncate the contents while editing it, so a better option would be to have backups. Your system administrator could (should?) take backups into a directory you couldn't delete, but a cheap simulation could be done with basically the same idea as above: Make a directory, and create a script that temporarily restores the write permission, makes backup copies into the directory and clears the write permission again.

Comment: And you can't add new files while write permission is denied.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use hardlinks with a backup folder, where I would keep a hardlink to each file I want to stay undeletable, just in case the deletion takes place. In case you delete the file, you can then create a hardlink from the backup dir to your home folder. This is not a perfect solution, but a relatively safe one.

```
$ mkdir filebak
$ echo content >file
$ ln file filebak/file
$ rm file
$ ln filebak/file file
$ cat file
content
```

Answer (score 1):

This only works for one file you specify in the myFile variable.

```
#
# Wrapper around /bin/rm to prevent accidental `rm myFile`
#
rm (){
local rm=$(which rm)

myFile="important.txt"

if [ -f "$myFile" ]; then
  $rm -iv "$myFile"
else
  $rm "$@"
fi

}
```

Remember to add this to /etc/profile then `./etc/profile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set directory to append-only mode like this:-

```
sudo chattr +a lol
```

Now you can add files into lol folder but cant delete lol and its childrens